# Quantity box for each size of product

Tags: magento-1.9

How do I make it so that the configurable product displays all sizes available with a quantity box next to them, so that the customer can order multiple sizes at once. Some products may even have different prices.

Similar to how this website does it: http://www.discountfootballkits.com/nike-park-vi-short-sleeve-football-shirt-black-white

Comment: Possibly better to use a bundle/grouped product for this instead?

Comment: Would it be possible to do this with options rather than configurable products. Thinking about it - there is no need for stock control, or for each item of clothing to be stored as a simple product.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps as per your requirement:

1. Create simple products (per size) & mark them as not visual individually.
2. Create one group product (Associate all simple products with them)
3. in front end open the group product.
4. Product page should give you options to update the quantity just like you wanted.